# How can I pass Collection to modal dialog window?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to know, if its possible to pass collection between pages. I mean to say i have a client-side JavaScript modal dialog on which I want to use my collection. Earlier I was using Session[] to share the value, but its becoming evil for me, as it always displays the first value. Any change in value in not updated.

So whenever my pop up is displayed I want the collection to get moved to the Child dialog. From there, i will extract the Collection, do some stuffs and again return it to parent page, preventing postbacks and session management.

I think i am clear to you guys. If not clear, please add comment.

Comment: What do you mean by not updated? You can always cast your Session variable to a proper type, change the values, and add it back to your session?

Comment: Yes, i know that but at some places i think my session is not updating with the new value.

Comment: Sounds like you need to interpret a .NET List<> collection with JavaScript. Is that right?

Comment: Yes from Codebehind, i want to pass Collection to child page

Comment: In that case I think you need to convert to something that JavaScript can readily consume such as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [try JSON](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/JSON-Basics/2/) or simply convert your List into a comma-delimited string which would be very easy to parse with JavaScript's [string split function](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php).

[RegisterArrayDeclaration(arrayName, arrayValue)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479302.aspx#clientsidescript_topic4) is another option. Check out the link.

From the link:

> If you need to create a client-side
>   JavaScript Array object with some set
>   values, use this method to add a value
>   to a specific array.

To add the values 1, 2, and 3 to a client-side Array object named FavoriteNumbers, you'd use the following server-side code:

```
RegisterArrayDeclaration("FavoriteNumbers", "1")
RegisterArrayDeclaration("FavoriteNumbers", "2")
RegisterArrayDeclaration("FavoriteNumbers", "3")
```

This code would emit the following client-side script:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
   var FavoriteNumbers =  new Array(1, 2, 3);
      // -->
</script>
```